# Sencha Themer 1.4.0 fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'i386,x86_64,unknown', need 'arm64e')

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd, extjs7, java

i'm using Sencha Themer 1.4.0
on Apple M1 with Monterey 12.4
java version "1.8.0_333"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_333-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.333-b02, mixed mode)

Always loading bar on open or create a theme remain at 99%.

On logs there is:

```
[2022-06-10 00:28:29.051] [DEBUG] [default] - Exception in thread "Thread-34" 
[2022-06-10 00:28:29.051] [DEBUG] [default] - java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /private/var/folders/d9/h_t37l0x3hj1h7r4vsd50ngw0000gn/T/jna--1385014272/jna2864571768082386130.tmp: dlopen(/private/var/folders/d9/h_t37l0x3hj1h7r4vsd50ngw0000gn/T/jna--1385014272/jna2864571768082386130.tmp, 0x0001): tried: '/private/var/folders/d9/h_t37l0x3hj1h7r4vsd50ngw0000gn/T/jna--1385014272/jna2864571768082386130.tmp' (fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'i386,x86_64,unknown', need 'arm64e'))
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1950)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1832)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:811)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1088)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:761)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:736)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:131)
    at com.sencha.jna.mac.Carbon.<clinit>(Carbon.java:11)
    at com.sencha.tools.watchers.FSEventWatchService$1.run(FSEventWatchService.java:41)
    at com.sencha.util.ThreadUtil$1.run(ThreadUtil.java:65)
    at com.sencha.util.ThreadUtil$2.run(ThreadUtil.java:162)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

How fix this problem?
Thanks